# Python namespace change of `import package.sub_module; from package import *`

Tags: python

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) says

> Consider this code:

```
import sound.effects.echo
import sound.effects.surround
from sound.effects import *
```

> In this example, the echo and surround modules are imported in the
>   current namespace because they are defined in the sound.effects
>   package when the from...import statement is executed. **(This also works
>   when __all__ is defined.)**

I try the following code

```
# package/
#     __init__.py
#     sub_module.py

import package.sub_module
from package import *
print(sub_module)
```

When `package/__init__.py` is empty, the code works fine. However, when `package/__init__.py` contains `__all__ = []`, `print(sub_module)` will raise `NameError`.
What is *(This also works when **all** is defined.)* from the documentation means?

---

The codes:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    sub_module.py # empty file
main.py
```

In main.py:

```
import package.sub_module
from package import *
print(sub_module)
```

When `package/__init__.py` is empty, executing `python3 main.py` gets 
    `<module 'package.sub_module' from '/path/to/package/sub_module.py'`

When `package/__init__.py` contains `__all__ = []`, executing `python3 main.py` gets

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(sub_module)
NameError: name 'sub_module' is not defined
```

Comment: can you share the complete code i.e. full exception traceback and also the init.py

Comment: Hi @NabeelAhmed, The post is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a module `package` defines `__all__`, it is the list of module names that are imported by `from package import *`

So if you define `__all__` as empty list, `from package import *` will import nothing.

Try defining it like this:

```
__all__ = ['sub_module']
```

Also note that you don't have to do `from package import *` to use `sub_module`

You can also just do:

```
import package.sub_module
print(package.sub_module)
```

Comment: +1 although I prefer avoiding `*` `import`s. And one could use `from package import sub_module` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: you have `__all__` set to empty list i.e. `from package import *` basically imports nothing

set it to `__all__ = ['submodule']` in `__init__.py`

---

> What exactly is **__all__** ?

In simplest words **all** help customizing the `from package import *` i.e. with **all** we can set what will be imported and what not.

**From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)**:

> The public names defined by a module are determined by checking the
>   module’s namespace for a variable named **all**; if defined, it must
>   be a sequence of strings which are names defined or imported by that
>   module. The names given in **all** are all considered public and are
>   required to exist. If **all** is not defined, the set of public names
>   includes all names found in the module’s namespace which do not begin
>   with an underscore character ('_'). **all** should contain the entire
>   public API. It is intended to avoid accidentally exporting items that
>   are not part of the API (such as library modules which were imported
>   and used within the module).

---

One important thing to note here is - **Imports without `*` are not affected by `__all__`** i.e. Members that are not mentioned in `__all__` are accessible from outside the module using direct import - `from <module> import <member>`.

**An Example**: the following code in a `module.py` explicitly exports the symbols `foo` and `bar`:

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']

waz = 5
foo = 10
def bar(): return 'bar'
```

These symbols can then be imported like so:

```
from foo import *

print foo
print bar

# now import `waz` will trigger an exception, 
# as it is not in the `__all__`, hence not a public member.
print waz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define `__all__`, then *only* the attributes mentioned there will be imported via `*`, while the excluded ones have to be imported *explicitly*. So either use

```
from package import submodule
```

or if you *really* want to use the (discouraged!) `from package import *`, declare

```
__all__ = ['submodule']
```

in `package`. Note how tedious it will become to keep this up-to-date...